# How do I create a dynamic sidebar instead of an index page using Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a beginner to Rails 5 and I am working on a NoteTaking app.

Given how notetaking apps are structured, I would like to have a dynamic sidebar with all the posts created appearing on the sidebar (and an possible ability to scroll within the sidebar) instead of having an index page.

Here's how I'd like it to look like (check the image below). While I do see the posts appearing on the sidebar, they're abruptly appearing multiple times as shown.

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
application.html.erb

<body>
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="logo">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
      <%= image_tag "logo.svg" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li class="category">Notes</li>
    <% @posts.all.each do |post| %>
      <li><%= post.title %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li class="category">Social</li>
    <li><%= link_to "Twitter", "#" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Facebook", "#" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Email", "#" %></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="sign_in">Admin Login</p>
</div>

<div id="main_content">
  <div id="header">
    <p>All Posts</p>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button"><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %></button>
      <button class="button">Log Out</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert") %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

There was a persistent error that said:
undefined method 'all' for nil:NilClass in the `application.html.erb`. More specifically here:

```
 <ul>
   <li class="category">Notes</li>
   <% @posts.all.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= post.title %></li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

Here's what I tried (no idea whether it is the way to do it..), I added the `@posts` to be available in all the views by adding it to the `application_controller.rb`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end  
end
```

I also included the `@posts` in the new and create methods in the `posts_controller.rb` like so:

```
def new
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I don't know how to proceed now. Can you please help me?! No man's land for me...Thanks!

Error stack from the server console:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 16:45:34 -0400
   (2.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/nikhilsamuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6zdP1vkLjn0BKq4/3qFqozrUhHepyW68Kc+dcJyc4wZMgCdBHBcRawLyXA+8pVnkJelurDFF72O5eruqxujQGw==", "post"=>{"title"=>"hello there", "body"=>"app"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31
  Post Create (2.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "hello there"], ["body", "app"], ["created_at", "2018-11-02 20:45:35.246718"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-02 20:45:35.246718"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31
   (3.4ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/12
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)


Started GET "/posts/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 16:45:35 -0400
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:68
  Rendering posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 633ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    19:
    20:       <ul>
    21:         <li class="category">Notes</li>
    22:         <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    23:           <li><%= post.title %></li>
    24:         <% end %>
    25:       </ul>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3194645343067756970_70256024775560'
Started GET "/posts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 16:45:40 -0400
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (30.6ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (37.1ms)
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22
Completed 200 OK in 84ms (Views: 73.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/posts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-02 16:45:41 -0400
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC
  ↳ app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:22
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 39.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: Did you try `@posts.each` instead of `@posts.all.each`

Comment: yes @jvillian. The error remains similar when I try to create a new post, this time it says undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @jvillian When I press the `create post` button, there is the error that shows up that I mentioned above. When I then press go back to the previous page, now I can see the new post that I created. But the error still appears.

Comment: Would you please add the error stack from your server console to your question?

Comment: Done! Added it in my question @jvillian

Comment: Where is your `show` action? And does it include the instantiation of the `@posts` variable? As you can see, the error is occurring after the redirect to the `show` action and that is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run it with the same code as you and come up with a few things;

First, your application.html.erb doesn't have a closing body tag, not sure if that's just a mistype.

Your html needs a change as mine threw an error when there are no actual posts created so I wrapped the loop in an unless statement;

```
   <ul>
    <li class="category">Notes</li>
    <% unless @posts.nil? %>
      <% @posts.all.each do |post| %>
        <li><%= post.title %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

As for the application_controller.rb, adding an index method there doesn't affect the index view of your models. Get right rid of that and leave the application_controller empty as it was. The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to just query the database in application.html.erb ie. So really, remove all the extra @posts variable you wrote into the controllers.

```
<ul>
    <li class="category">Notes</li>
    <% Post.all.reverse.each do |post| %>
        <li><%= post.title %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

This just makes a query from each loaded page, instead of using a variable from a controller. No doubles, no nil calls.

In my opinion, the best way to do this would be to create a fragment that renders your sidebar with an @sidebar_posts variable or something similar. But that's probably for the further down the line.

Cheers and good luck!

EDIT:

Saw the other answer after posting, to combine the two you could change the html to;

```
<ul>
<li class="category">Notes</li>
  <% posts_for_sidebar.each do |post| %>
    <li><%= post.title %></li>
  <% end %>
```

and then add the following method into the application_helper.rb as suggested;

```
def posts_for_sidebar
@sidebar_posts = Post.all.reverse
```

end

But you still need to remove all the extra @post instance variables in the controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. As for the body tag, I did have it but I shared only the relevant code in `application.html.erb`. Thanks for the other helpful information. I didn't know I could use helpers for this (beginner as I said). When you said "create a fragment that renders your sidebar with an @sidebar_posts variable", did you mean the same info that you added in your EDIT? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use the code you suggested above saying: `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. I'm not sure why. I defined the helper method too.

Comment: Got it. I made a mistake, I added @posts_for_sidebar instead of posts_for_sidebar! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on an instance variable in your application layout, that's simply not how it should be done.

Instead add a helper method, e.g. `posts_for_navigation`, into your `ApplicationHelper` and get the posts from there. This will mean a lot less code in the controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information, I understood it now.